# How to write unit tests for continuous Combine publisher without using wait(for:timeout:)?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, combine

Imagine, we have a `sut` as a publisher which publishes values continuously and never finishes. On change of some input (ex: we change some mocked @Published property which our `sut` depends on), it emits an event.

We're collecting these events in `results` array and then checking if there is an exact expected number of events, not less and not more.

The problem is - how to check there are no more events after what we expect to be emitted? Without `wait` method we don't know when it's time to check the `results` array.

`wait` will work but it feels for me like a crutch for Combine. Because the good unit tests should be fast (see F.I.R.S.T principles of unit testing). And these `wait`s looks more like anti-pattern.

I also couldn't find an Apple's recommendation on this.

Comment: "wait will work but it feels for me like a crutch for Combine" I'm unclear what you mean by that. Testing asynchronous material requires asynchronous testing.  That is why asynchronous testing exists! Our tests use `wait` all the time. You don't have to wait very long, just long enough to prove the hypothesis true or false.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. By `crutch for Combine` I meant a suboptimal solution just to fill the gap (sorry for the vague language). Yes, your point about asynchronous code also makes sense. In our codebase, we have a lot of asynchronous code (most of it, I would say), and using `wait` each time will make it very slow at some point, it's just a question of time. Our tests performs ~15min on CI already. But on the other hand, it can sound like a premature optimization from me, perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

You need a test scheduler, which is basically a virtual time scheduler that will let you control when the time-based events will be published. So for example you can fire all the events at once.
Combine does not have build-in a test scheduler, but you can use an open source test scheduler called [Entwine](https://github.com/tcldr/Entwine)

Comment: Thanks! I also saw other implementations before... It can be an option, but I had a hard time forcing myself to include 3rd party code into my project. I wonder if this is the only possible solution?

Comment: I can not think of something else. You either have to wait (not advisable, if you can avoid it, will cause slow unit tests and risky making it flaky) or you have to mock the time for the time-based events(and invoke the delayed actions immediately). Only third party support is offered for the second option

Comment: writing a test scheduler is not that complex (see [scheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/scheduler)). for immediate execution you could use [ImmediateScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/immediatescheduler)